# how to update pHead for linked list after the first element is removed in the function?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

the linked list is 0 1 2 3 4 5, 
the only problem in searchRemove function is if argument key is pHead 0, 
i have to go back to main() to update pHead: pHead = searchRemove(pHead, 0).

What if i just want to write searchRemove(pHead, 0) in main(), how do I change my searchFunction outside of main() to make it update itself for pHead?

I think I might need to write as searchRemove(node **pHead, int key). but I have no clue how to change rest of the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int data;
    node *next;
};
node *newNode(int data=0, node *next=NULL){
    node x = {data, next};
    node *p = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    *p = x;
    return p;
}
void showNode(const node *p){
    while(p != NULL){
        printf("%d",p->data);
        p= p->next;       
    }
    printf("\n");
}

node *Delete(node *p){
    while(p != NULL){
        node *pTemp = p;
        p = p->next;
        free(pTemp);
    }
    return NULL;   
}

node *searchRemove(node *pHead, int key){
    node *p = pHead, *pA = NULL;
    while(p != NULL){
        if(p->data == key){
            node *pTemp = p->next;
            if(pA) pA->next = pTemp;
            free (p);
            return pTemp;
        }
        pA = p;
        p = p->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    node *pHead = NULL;
    for(int i=5; i>=0; i--)
        pHead = newNode(i,pHead);

    //Output   
    showNode(pHead);

    searchRemove(pHead, 2);
    showNode(pHead);

    //Delete all
    pHead = Delete(pHead);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a pointer to pointer to head so that you can change it within the function if head is to be deleted.
You need to change the head when the `key` is equal to the first node i.e. when `pA` is `NULL`.

```
 node *searchRemove(node **pHead, int key){
 node *p = *pHead, *pA = NULL;
 while(p != NULL)
 {
    if(p->data == key){
        node *pTemp = p->next;
        if(pA) 
           pA->next = pTemp;
        else
           *pHead=pTemp;  //make head point to new head
         free (p);
        return pTemp;
    }
    pA = p;
    p = p->next;
 }
 return NULL;
 }
```

Comment: how about in main ()? how do i change below?
searchRemove(pHead, 99)

Comment: i changed to 
node *h = pHead;
searchRemove(&h, 99); but got a crush...

Comment: btw, i dont understand why add * before pHead
, why cant be node *p = pHead;

Comment: because `pHead` is not of type `node*`, it's of type`node**`.